# Не получается склонировать проект GitLab (ключ добавлен)

Tags: git, github, gitlab, репозиторий, git-clone

> Ошибки выглядят так

1. **(по SSH)**

   Cloning into 'prog-frontend'...
   ssh: connect to host git.gateline.net port 22: Connection timed out
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
2. **(по https)**

   Cloning into 'angular-frontend'...
   remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
   fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git...

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `git credential-cache exit` и снова clone

Comment: А права доступа к репозиторию установлены?

Comment: Проблема решена, запись в ответе к вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в номере (Port 22) . Изменил по гайду и все заработало [гайд по смене Port SSH](https://putty.org.ru/articles/change-default-sshd-port.html)