# Доступ в gitlab

Tags: ssh, gitlab

Добавляю ключик публичный в гитлаб, к себе в аккаунт. Затем, проверяю, что есть доступ:

`ssh -T git@git.***.ru`

> Welcome to GitLab, @e.urvanov!

После этого пытаюсь заклонить проект. Но получаю `premission denied`. Через веб-морду доступ к проекту есть. В чём проблема?

> remote:  remote:
> ======================================================================== remote:  remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
> remote:  remote:
> ======================================================================== remote:  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Ответ на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936471/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-gitlab-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD) прочитал. Это вряд ли связано с портом, так как тест гитлаба проходит успешно, как указано выше в моём вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует прописать в `~/.ssh/config` следующее:

```
### ***
Host git.***.ru
User git
IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa_***
```

Comment: не очень полезный, по-моему, «вопросоответ»: 1. ни в вопросе ни в ответе ни слова про то, что в url-е не указан корректный пользователь (иначе зачем бы в ответе нужна была строка `user git`?) 2. ни в вопросе ни в ответе ни слова про то, что секретный rsa-ключ сохранён не под каноническим именем `id_rsa`.